# Mongoid 6, Rails 5, HABTM "unpermitted parmeter"

Tags: mongodb, ruby-on-rails-5, rails-api, mongoid6

I've been doing RoR for years, but this is my first project with Mongo (also my first api-only project). I'm having a rough time with HABTM associations and I suspect it has to do with params, but I'm not sure what else to try.

Here's what I've got:

```
class Project
  include Mongoid::Document
  field :name, type: String
  field :start_date, type: Date
  field :target_date, type: Date

  has_and_belongs_to_many :users
end

class User
  include Mongoid::Document
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable,
         :jwt_authenticatable, jwt_revocation_strategy: JWTBlacklist

  field :email,              type: String
  field :_id, type: String, default: ->{ email }
  { ... devise stuff ...}
  has_and_belongs_to_many :projects
end
```

In my projects controller, I have this for parameters:

```
def project_params
      params.permit(:id, :name, :start_date, :target_date, :description, user_ids: [])
    end
```

And yes, I've also tried doing {user_ids: []}.

When I use Postman to make a URL PUT request to attempt to add users to a project, I get an "unpermitted parameter" error. But ... I'm permitting that parameter, right?

I'm kind of going nuts because I don't know if I have a Mongo problem, a Rails 5 problem, or an API problem. All other calls are working fine.

```
Started PUT "/rapi/projects/3" for 127.0.0.1 at 2017-02-15 22:55:10 -0500
Overwriting existing field _id in class JWTBlacklist.
Overwriting existing field _id in class User.
Processing by Api::V1::ProjectsController#update as JSON
  Parameters: {"user_ids"=>"test@gmail.com", "id"=>"3"}
MONGODB | localhost:27017 | anthem.find | STARTED | {"find"=>"users", "filter"=>{"_id"=>"test@gmail.com"}}
MONGODB | localhost:27017 | anthem.find | SUCCEEDED | 0.000363703s
Overwriting existing field _id in class Project.
MONGODB | localhost:27017 | anthem.find | STARTED | {"find"=>"projects", "filter"=>{"_id"=>"3"}}
MONGODB | localhost:27017 | anthem.find | SUCCEEDED | 0.000244022s
Unpermitted parameters: user_ids, format
Overwriting existing field _id in class Release.
Completed 204 No Content in 20ms
```

I'd appreciate any ideas about what else I might try.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> But ... I'm permitting that parameter, right?

Not quite. You're permitting `user_ids` as an array. But you send it as a scalar value. This is enough difference for strong params to not let the data through.

Make up your mind and do either one (permit array and send array) or the other (permit scalar and send scalar).

Comment: Ah! My problem wasn't a rails problem, it was that I didn't really know how to use Postman. Thank you for your response, that solved it! :)

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use devise_parameter_sanitizer.permit

```
devise_parameter_sanitizer.permit(:id, :name, :start_date, :target_date, :description, keys: [:username])
```